# QUERY function with one result returns value beneath the formula cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

When I use the `=QUERY` function in Google Sheets, it returns the value in the cell beneath where I typed the function. I want the returned value to appear in the cell I typed the function. Currently, I have

`=QUERY(Data!$L:$N,"select avg(N) where L = '"&CONCATENATE(B$1,$A2)&"'")`

in cell B2, and it is returning the value in B3.

How can I return the value into B2 instead of B3?

Comment: Because the word AVG sits in B2? The documentation suggests that is normal. It has a similar example with MAX.

Answer (score 13):

It is returning you an array containing the name of the calculating SQL function first and then the result. To subvert this behavior, you could do the following.

```
=INDEX(QUERY(Data!$L:$N,"select avg(N) where L = '"&CONCATENATE(B$1,$A2)&"'"),2)
```

Comment: you can also use something like this
`=QUERY(Data!$L:$N,"select avg(N) where L = '"&CONCATENATE(B$1,$A2)&"' limit 1")`
if you just want one result only instead of an array

Answer (score 7):

The query language itself allows for this by permitting application of a blank label:

```
=QUERY(Data!$L:$N,"select avg(N) where L='"&B$1&$A2&"' label avg(N)''")
```

Comment: way more direct for this case of running a scalar query 